# Remove the "server" name header in iis7.5 for Classic ASP app

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I am working with a classic asp application running on IIS7.5.

The requirements ask to remove all miscelaneous headers, including the "Server" header.

I have been able to remove all but that.

Does anyone have a method by which this can be done?

I saw one method which accommodates it via an installation of the MS urlScan addin, but I am looking to avoid this.

Comment: I fear this is not possible with plain classic ASP code, this header appears to be in the "core" of IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but not via code:

IIS7.x - via HttpModule

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/howardvanrooijen/archive/2009/08/25/cloaking-your-asp-net-mvc-web-application-on-iis-7.aspx

II6.0 - via URLscan (from microsoft)

https://web.archive.org/web/20210506093425/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120209-1.aspx#postadlink

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc242650.aspx